# Consulta Mysql com coluna criada por select em outras tabelas

Tags: mysql

Bom dia galera.

Supondo uma regra de negocio onde eu tenha restaurantes, e cada usuário possa seguir vários restaurantes, eu crie uma **tabela_restaurante**, **tabela_usuario** e **tabela_restaurante_usuario_seguindo**.
Dai, quando um usuario começar a seguir um restaurante, um registro na **tabela_restaurante_usuario_seguindo** é criado, guardando a id_restaurante e id_usuario. Até ai tudo bem.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: supondo que meu usuario esteja logado no meu aplicativo, quando eu listar os restaurantes, quero que seja mostrado todos os restaurantes, mas que na consulta seja criada uma coluna dizendo se o usuário logado segue ou não aquele restaurante. É possível e viável atingir esse resultado através de uma consulta Mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você possa usar algo do tipo:

```
SELECT R.*, RU.IDUsuario AS ExisteUsuario FROM tabela_restaurante R
LEFT JOIN tabela_restaurante_usuario_seguindo RU ON RU.IDRestaurante = R.IDRestaurante
WHERE RU.IDUsuario = <ID DO USUÁRIO QUE VOCÊ DESEJA PROCURAR>
```

Neste cenário você poderá valiar. Se o conteúdo de ExisteUsuario for diferente de NULL então o usuário segue aquele restaurante.

Comment: Valeu brother, consegui fazer a consulta =)